# Is there a detailed explanation for how the voting system algorithm is defined in The Prefect?

Tags: alastair-reynolds

I was sitting in the car driving to work and talking about democracy with my girlfriend. I remembered the asteroid in The Prefect where the citizens on the rock had a greater valued vote.

My question is about how the system is designed more specifically the details of the algorithm. Is there any more detail about the voting system or a similar system not necessarily from Alistair Reynolds (this is just a starting point) out on the web anywhere? I think it is slightly more than just a nice idea and maybe there is a similar system in use somewhere in the real world? Who knows, maybe it is just a feature of a futuristic novel. Any ideas, links to websites or other questions welcome.

UPDATE: I know it is annoying when people ask questions without doing a little research themselves, so as I have just arrived in the office I have done a little Googling and found:

http://web.math.princeton.edu/math_alive/Voting/Lab2/Weighted.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banzhaf_power_index

I will continue my search but please feel free to post a link or share other details you may know about.

Comment: The tricky thing here is that in the novel, people are given more votes because they voted correctly or because their vote made things turn out better. In the real world, determining if a vote was "good" or "correct" is completely subjective. I would love to hear a more detailed explanation of what Reynolds might have had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent some time looking for examples but I have only just been able to spend a bit more time looking at some more resources. In combination with the links in the original question and due to a lack of answers I have decided to answer this question myself.

I found this link and combined it with the links in the first question to understand further the rules around weighted systems:

http://www.ctl.ua.edu/math103/power/wtvoting.htm

Comment: If anyone can come with a better answer I will be willing to award the bounty to them as I do feel my 'answer' is a little lame.